# How to get the string from start of line to first openning bracket?

Tags: c#, regex

How can I get this with Regex, C#?

string s = "**1.8.4*03**(00000.000*kWh)";

**1.8.4*03**

Everytime, string has an openning bracket...

Edit:

XX(XX)

XX are dynamic strings, brackets static...

Comment: Is it a fixed length string you're trying to get? Any other formatting that needs to be considered as part of the string?

Comment: Do you want it using `regex` only?

Comment: XX(XX), XX are dynamic strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this** (with "positive-lookahead") :

```
.+?(?=\()
```

**Demo :**

<del>http://regexr.com?38bnt</del>

http://regex101.com/r/wD4oG1

Comment: @ErçinDedeoğlu Hmmm, I don't think I get what you mean.... What's an `RSL error`?

Comment: @ErçinDedeoğlu Ah, ok! It's still working for me though. That's weird. OK, so here's another one : http://regex101.com/r/wD4oG1

Answer (score 1):

This regex will do for you:

```
^([^\(]*)\(
```

It means capture until the `(` from the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to use `RegEx` for this.

You can use [String.IndexOf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [String.Substring()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods to achieve this simply.

Try This:

```
string s = "1.8.4*03(00000.000*kWh)";
int startIndex = s.IndexOf("(");
if(startIndex>=0)
{
s=s.Substring(0, startIndex);
}
```